# Is there any way to do this sort little bit smarter?

Tags: sorting, erlang

If I have a `List = [1,3,5,2,4,6]` and I want it to be sorted to `[6,5,4,3,2,1]`.
I can do `lists:reverse(lists:sort(List)).`.

But I wondering if there is any internal function in Erlang can do this sort directly?

Comment: If you think it is a good answer, kindly pick it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is. [lists:sort/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sort-2).

```
lists:sort(fun(A, B) -> B < A end, List).
[6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

I highly recommend bookmarking [Erldocs](http://erldocs.com/) also.